# Semantic UI - Search options are blank

Tags: javascript, json, search, semantic-ui

So I'm trying to figure out how Semantic UI's Search module works. I've been testing it on some test data:

```
const testdata = [
    {
    "id": 7,
    "created_at": "2020-03-24 08:40:42",
    "updated_at": "2020-03-25 10:10:59",
    "name": "NameX",
    "email": "namex@email.no",
    "phone": "94860509"
    },
    {
    "id": 8,
    "created_at": "2020-03-25 10:11:10",
    "updated_at": "2020-03-25 10:11:10",
    "name": "NameY",
    "email": "namey@gmail.com",
    "phone": "94860509"
    },
    {
    "id": 9,
    "created_at": "2020-03-31 15:55:06",
    "updated_at": "2020-03-31 15:55:19",
    "name": "Lucifer",
    "email": "lucifer@gmail.com",
    "phone": "58893177"
    },
    {
    "id": 10,
    "created_at": "2020-03-31 15:55:41",
    "updated_at": "2020-03-31 15:55:41",
    "name": "Morningstar",
    "email": "morningstar@gmail.com",
    "phone": "12345678"
    },
    {
    "id": 11,
    "created_at": "2020-04-01 16:13:39",
    "updated_at": "2020-04-01 16:13:39",
    "name": "Superwhale",
    "email": "superwhale@gmail.com",
    "phone": "18181818"
    }
];
```

Currently, it seems like it's actually making the search. There are two names with the word "name" in them - `NameX` and `NameY`, and it's giving me two results, the problem is that those results are just blank.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/568XV.png

This is how the search element is configured:

```
$('.ui.search').search({
    source: testdata,
    showNoResults: true,
    ignoreDiacritics: true,
    searchFullText: false,
    searchFields: [
        'name'
    ]
});
```

I've been going through the documentation and it seems like it should work, but it doesn't. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. The search module of Semantic UI expects certain keys, so my equivalent "name" would have to be "title". I fixed it by going through the JSON and replacing every occurance of

> "name":

with

> "title":

I tried using

```
fields: {
  title   : 'name'
}
```

but that didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

try filter result by function

```
const filterNameObj = (array) => array.filter(item => {
  if((item.name === 'NameX') || (item.name === 'NameY')) return item
})

filterNameObj(testdata )
```

```js
const testdata = [
  {
  "id": 7,
  "created_at": "2020-03-24 08:40:42",
  "updated_at": "2020-03-25 10:10:59",
  "name": "NameX",
  "email": "namex@email.no",
  "phone": "94860509"
  },
  {
  "id": 8,
  "created_at": "2020-03-25 10:11:10",
  "updated_at": "2020-03-25 10:11:10",
  "name": "NameY",
  "email": "namey@gmail.com",
  "phone": "94860509"
  },
  {
  "id": 9,
  "created_at": "2020-03-31 15:55:06",
  "updated_at": "2020-03-31 15:55:19",
  "name": "Lucifer",
  "email": "lucifer@gmail.com",
  "phone": "58893177"
  },
  {
  "id": 10,
  "created_at": "2020-03-31 15:55:41",
  "updated_at": "2020-03-31 15:55:41",
  "name": "Morningstar",
  "email": "morningstar@gmail.com",
  "phone": "12345678"
  },
  {
  "id": 11,
  "created_at": "2020-04-01 16:13:39",
  "updated_at": "2020-04-01 16:13:39",
  "name": "Superwhale",
  "email": "superwhale@gmail.com",
  "phone": "18181818"
  }
];

const filterNameObj = (array) => array.filter(item => {
  if((item.name === 'NameX') || (item.name === 'NameY')) return item
})

console.log(filterNameObj(testdata))
```

Comment: How would that help with what I'm trying to do exactly?

Comment: All that would do is remove the other objects from the search.